# Underscore.js code is not working - gives undefined

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying this code on jsfiddle, and I am not really sure why it does not work:

```
var utm_cookie_names = ['utm_campaign','utm_source','utm_medium', 'utm_term', 'utm_content'];

var campaign = _.each(utm_cookie_names, function(value) {
    return _.pick({'utm_campaign': 'campaign', 'utm_source': 'source','utm_medium': 'medium','age': '20', 'name': 'ankita'}, value);
});

console.log(campaign);
```

I keep getting undefined in my console every time I press run. Any idea why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gjpq1c0k/1/ - looks fine

Comment: what is the desired output - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gjpq1c0k/2/

Comment: Are you looking for `_.map` or `_.find` (instead of `_.each`)?

Comment: hi @ArunPJohny, yeah it seems to be working when u try it. but the code on my browser was not working. don't understand why

Comment: bob_d, is Underscore.js properly defined on the page that you're trying to execute this from? Perhaps there's an _ object on the page that's not actually the Underscore.js library?

If you visit http://underscorejs.org/ and open a console on that page, then execute the script (since you know it's defined properly there) and it works, you've got something wrong with the dependency on the page you're otherwise testing against.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using _.each

```
var campaign = _.each(utm_cookie_names, function(value) {
    return _.pick({'utm_campaign': 'campaign',
                   'utm_source': 'source',
                   'utm_medium': 'medium',
                   'age': '20',
                   'name': 'ankita'
    }, value);
});
```

Use _.filter instead

```
var campaign = _.filter(utm_cookie_names, function(value) {
    return _.pick({'utm_campaign': 'campaign',
                   'utm_source': 'source',
                   'utm_medium': 'medium',
                   'age': '20',
                   'name': 'ankita'
    }, value);
});
```

The function _.each doesn't return anything.

Just allows you to change each element of a list, one by one.